# Kendo UI Grid collapse is not working in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, kendo-ui

I have a modal window and a grid is populated when it loads. The grid has a grouping implemented on it works fine . but if I reopen the modal the collapse functionality is not working on Kendo UI grid. If I close on reopen the modal window collapse works again. it means it works every alternate times I open the window. Have anyone faced this issue. Please let me know if someone knows the fix.

Comment: Such strange issues usually occur when you **[create multiple Kendo UI widget instances over the same HTML element](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/jquery-initialization#duplicate-initialization)**. Please verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did declarative initialization for the grid and it worked.